# How to stop Unity3D Monodevelop from copying reference dlls into target directory

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have a monodevelop sln with a sub project that builds out a dll into the Assets/myplugin/ target directory.

I can not get it to stop copying the reference dlls. i.e. UnityEngine, UnityEditor.

I don't have this problem with VisualStudio on the PC. But on the Mac its driving me crazy.

How do I configure MonoDevelop to not copy reference dlls with dll i'm creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for Visual Studio and hence MonoDevelop.

In Visual Studio on the Reference file you can right click to view the properties and select "Local Copy" = false.

Same in MonoDevelop and VisualStudio(mac).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you output the dlls outside your Unity project, you can use [Link & Sync](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/75421) to set it up so you can compile the dll then click a button to import it. The Pro version allows you to set it up to happen automatically whenever the external source (the compiled dll) changes.

Comment: Thanks, we were in the process of writing something similar to Link & Sync. I guess i could just get Unity to copy the dlls from a folder outside of the Assets/ folder.